# 2.170.1\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe' failed with exit code 1

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to run my automation pipeline on Private hosted agent and getting error as Test Run Failed.
Error: The process 'C:\agent_work_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.170.1\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe' failed with exit code 1
Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Error: The process 'C:\agent_work_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.170.1\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe' failed with exit code 1 Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.

Based on the error message, the reason for this issue should be that the VSTest task supported .Net Framework 4.6.2 from version 2.170.1.

You need to  check the .NET framework version installed on the build agent machine. If the .NET framework version installed on the machine is 4.6.1 or less than that then can you please try upgrading the .Net framework version to 4.6.2.

Here is a doc about the requirement about the [Visual Studio test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops#check-prerequisites):

> If you're using a Windows self-hosted agent, be sure that your machine
> has this prerequisite installed:
>
> .NET Framework 4.6.2 or a later version

In addition, you can try to use the Visual Studio test task version 1.

[image]